# javascript split with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to split characters into array using javascript with regex

foo=foobar=&foobar1=foobar2=

into

foo, foobar=,
foobar1, foobar2=

Sorry for not being clear, let me re describe the scenario.
First i would split it by "&" and want to post process it later.

```
str=foo=foobar=&foobar1=foobar2=
var inputvars=str.split("&")
for(i=0;i<inputvars.length;i++){
   var param = inputvars[i].split("=");
   console.log(param);
}
```

returns

```
[foo,foobar]
[]
[foobar1=foobar2]
[]
```

I tried to use .split("=") but foobar= got splited out as foobar.

I essentially want it to be

```
[foo,foobar=]
[foobar1,foobar2=]
```

Any help with using javascript to split first occurence of = only?

Comment: Is that really the format?  where does it come from.  I've never seen something with the `=&` like that.  Other than that, it looks like part of a query string.

Comment: Can you clarify the precise rules you want to split by? Is this two levels of splitting, the first on `&`, then on the resulting components using `=`?

Answer (score 1):

```
/^([^=]*)=(.*)/.exec('foo=foobar=&foobar1=foobar2=')
```

or simpler to write but using the newer "lazy" operator:

```
/(.*?)=(.*)/.exec('foo=foobar=&foobar1=foobar2=')
```

Comment: It return the following results 
["foo=foobar=&foobar1=foobar2=", "foo", "foobar=&foobar1=foobar2="] which is not intended..

Comment: @flyclassic -- RegExp always gives the whole match as the first argument.  Are the second and third the answer you need?

Comment: i know, but the results are still not what i intended LOL
it should be ['foo', 'foobar=', 'foobar1', 'foobar2=']

Comment: @flyclassic - You want *every other* equal-sign stripped off?

Comment: thanks malvolio... you help me solve my problem already...i guess i wasnt clear earlier

Answer (score 0):

from malvolio, i got to conclusion below

```
var str = 'foo=foobar=&foobar1=foobar2=';
var inputvars = str.split("&");
var pattern =  /^([^=]*)=(.*)/;
for (counter=0; counter<inputvars.length; counter++){

     var param = pattern.exec(inputvars[counter]);         
    console.log(param)
}
```

and results (which is what i intended)

```
[foo,foobar=]
[foobar1,foobar2=]
```

Thanks to @malvolio hint of regex
Cheers